# The security settings could not be applied, Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' while installing?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to change my MySQL password so I uninstalled it and then again tries to install it. while installing it keeps on showing the error.[click to show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtJF2.jpg)

Comment: ?? what error ?

Comment: host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this mysql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because an older MySQL database (instance) exists in your system. To find where it is located, open the my.ini file in the MySQL installation folder and find '#Path to the database root' string. The line next to it specifies the default path to the database folder. By default this will be pointing to

`"C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/"`

Remove the existing MySQL installation. Next, open the parent folder of the database location ( ie if the path is "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/" then open the folder that is the parent of "MySQL" folder). Here it will be "C:/ProgramData". Then delete the "MySQL" folder (with all its contents) in it.

Now install a fresh copy. You will see that it works like charm!